# Change content of a textbox with a source control

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, ms-access-2003

I have to do some changes to a program that runs on Access 2003.

I have a form where clicking on a certain button will change the text of a textbox depending on what is selected (image research).
Originally, this textbox is linked to another hidden textbox that contain the original path for this image (the one in the database / unedited).

My problem consists of the following: when I want the textbox that is linked to the DB to change to match the other textbox (containing the newest path), and thus allowing Access to save the changes, it just doesn't work. The textbox linked to the DB just goes blank.

Here is the code I work with in VBA:

```
Public Sub SearchForImage(ByVal txtName As String, ByVal txtAuto As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim B As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        Me.Controls(txtName).SetFocus
        Me.Controls(txtName).Text = ""
        B = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    Me.Controls(txtAuto).SetFocus
    Me.Controls(txtAuto).Text = ""
    Me.Controls(txtAuto) = B
End Sub
```

This allows me to change the text (along with another bit of code that isn't liked to the problem [it just make the text go blank before inputting the new value]). "txtName" represents the diffrent textbox I send to the function (these are not linked to the database in any way), and "txtAuto" the textbox linked to the database with a source control.

Does anyone have an idea of why I can't change the value of this ? Is it because the textbox is linked with a source control ? Would it be better to directly save the content of 'B' in the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure how well I understand what you're trying to do.  However, I think you should use those controls' `.Value` properties instead of `.Text`, and then you don't need to `.SetFocus` first.

```vb
'On Error Resume Next ' <-- avoid this whenever possible
Dim B As String
With Application.FileDialog(1) ' msoFileDialogOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = True Then
        B = .SelectedItems(1)
        Me.Controls(txtName).Value = B
    End If
End With
Me.Controls(txtAuto).Value = B
```

That may not do exactly what you want.  However, without `On Error Resume Next` active, at least it may give you and us a clearer understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped to correct the bug. The problem was also coming from the fact that some of the image paths were exceding the 255 char. limit and weren't saved because of this.